# Ajax request return an error 400

Tags: jquery, ajax

I make an ajax request that connects me to my API for registering a user.

The problem that I do not really understand is that I get a 400 (bad request) error, while I have my registration was done (I can connect and in the database the new registrant is present) .

Here is my request (the userinfo contains all the fields required by the API and when I do console.log(userinfo) I get the necessary info)

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.asaplace.v-labs.fr/users', // url de l'API
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST', // méthode REST utilisée POST, GET, PUT ou DELETE
  data: userinfo, // paramètres/corps de la requête
  success: function(xhr) {
    if (xhr.status === 201) {
      alert('Vous Avez été inscrit avec succès!');
      $("#closeSignIn").click();
    }
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    if (xhr.status === 400) {
      console.log(userinfo);
      alert('Un des champs a mal été renseigné');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems like the request is missing from your question...?

Comment: Sorry, just forgot

Answer (score 0):

Here you GO with this snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.asaplace.v-labs.fr/users', // url de l'API
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST', // méthode REST utilisée POST, GET, PUT ou DELETE
  data: userinfo, // paramètres/corps de la requête
  success: function(xhr) {
    if (xhr.status === 201) {
      alert('Vous Avez été inscrit avec succès!');
      $("#closeSignIn").click();
    }
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    if (xhr.status === 400) {
      console.log(userinfo);
      alert('Un des champs a mal été renseigné');
    }
  }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, I dont think this is the problem because my ajax request is acive only when the user click on a sign in button. Also I use React.js and Node.js and jquery is import from the module

Comment: did you run `snippet` ?` your query fired successfully, check `snippet` once.

Comment: Yes I tried to snippet but like "userinfo" is undefined i've got an error        
{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: userinfo is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 19,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: for that, you have to pass store something in `userinfo` and pass it like `userinfo : "data_you_want_pass"` or `userinfo : userinfo`